# Whole memory eaten on sda7

Tags: 18.04, disk, disk-usage

I have couple files on my disk only however something is eating most of disk space, how can I check and remove this unnecessary files?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda7        79G   56G   19G  76% /
tmpfs           7.8G  8.4M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1650
/dev/loop0      145M  145M     0 100% /snap/slack/19
/dev/loop5      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
/dev/loop7       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop9      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop10     4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop6       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/375
/dev/loop12     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop4       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
/dev/loop2       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1279
/dev/loop13      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/loop11     157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop14     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/loop15     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/123
/dev/loop16      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop8      4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/501
/dev/loop3      174M  174M     0 100% /snap/skype/109
/dev/loop17     185M  185M     0 100% /snap/eclipse/40
/dev/loop19     181M  181M     0 100% /snap/spotify/35
/dev/loop18     135M  135M     0 100% /snap/slack/20
/dev/loop20     161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop21      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop22     182M  182M     0 100% /snap/spotify/36
/dev/loop23     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop24     173M  173M     0 100% /snap/skype/101
/dev/sda1       646M   62M  585M  10% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   20K  1.6G   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           1.6G   52K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Try `sudo du -sm /*` or `sudo baobab`.

Comment: More than likely it's old Ubuntu kernels or log files. Show me `ls -al /boot` and `ls -alt /var/log`

Answer (score 0):

```
/dev/sda7        79G   56G   19G  76% /
```

`/` is the root of your whole system. Randomly deleting files/directories in `/` is not a good idea.

To see large open files:

```
sudo lsof / | awk '{if($7 > 1048576) print $7/1048576 "MB" " " $9 }' | sort -n -u
```

To see files that are open but deleted,

```
sudo lsof / | grep -E 'PID|\(deleted\)'
```